# What post-hoc test should be used for a glmer model with a continious and a categorical predictor variable?

Tags: r, lme4, posthoc

I'm a bit of a newbie with stats and R, so need a bit of direction to find a suitable post-hoc test for my glmer model.

The model has a binary dependent variable (absent/present) and the predictor variables are interactive terms between a continuous variable(eg temp) and a categorical variable (species, n=3). Only interactive terms, rather than the continuous factor in isolation, produce significant results when an anova is run on the model. Species by itself has a large effect because one species is much rarer than the others. I'm trying to tease apart how the presence of these species varies across pH and between species.

I've tried lsmeans test with Tukey, and Firth's Bias-Reduced Logistic Regression, emmeans. I ran the effects function on the interactive terms, so had a rough expectation of what a post hoc could show, but the results logistf (firth's) have produced I was not expecting. Emmeans and tukey both gave the same results and ignored the continuous variable I assume because it's not a factor.

When I run firth's regression it produces chi-squared and p values that are either infinity for chi values or the p values astronomically small, even though what I saw through effects suggested no significant difference. I can't tell with the interactive term if there truly is an effect of the environmental variable or if the significant effect is because of the difference in species. Based on what I have seen of the logistf function, I didn't think it would produce a chi-square score. Is this an issue in coding or is it because of my data?

If I wasn't clear enough about something please let me know and if anyone has any suggestions or advice, they would be massively appreciated. Thanks!
The model and test code I used are below:

```
###glmer model
Large<-glmer(Abs.Pres~ Species:Q.Depth+Species:Conductivity+Species:Temp+Species:pH+Species:DO.P+(1|QID),
             nAGQ=0,
             family=binomial,
             data=Stacked_Pref)
anova(Large)
 Output:Analysis of Variance Table
                     npar  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value
Species:Q.Depth         3 234.904  78.301 78.3014
Species:Conductivity    3  32.991  10.997 10.9970
Species:Temp            3  39.001  13.000 13.0004
Species:pH              3  25.369   8.456  8.4562
Species:DO.P            3  34.930  11.643 11.6434

###Firths
 Lp<-logistf(Abs.Pres~Species:pH, data=Stacked_Pref, contrasts.arg=list(pH="contr.treatment", Species="contr.sum"))
> Lp
logistf(formula = Abs.Pres ~ Species:pH, data = Stacked_Pref, 
    contrasts.arg = list(pH = "contr.treatment", Species = "contr.sum"))
Model fitted by Penalized ML
Confidence intervals and p-values by Profile Likelihood 

                         coef   se(coef) lower 0.95 upper 0.95    Chisq            p
(Intercept)         1.9711411 0.57309880  0.8552342  3.1015114 12.09107 5.066380e-04
SpeciesGoby:pH     -0.3393185 0.07146049 -0.4804047 -0.2003108 23.31954 1.371993e-06
SpeciesMosquito:pH -0.3001385 0.07127771 -0.4408186 -0.1614419 18.24981 1.937453e-05
SpeciesRFBE:pH     -0.4771393 0.07232469 -0.6200179 -0.3365343 45.73750 1.352096e-11

Likelihood ratio test=267.0212 on 3 df, p=0, n=3945
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Is this a coding question (suitable for this site) or a statistics question.  If the later consider posting this question on CrossValidated https://stats.stackexchange.com. Check out [ask] for guidance.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. I've posted across to Cross Validated as well, but in regards to coding I wanted to also see why I was getting chi square instead of z scores like I have seen for other logistf output, in case that was a coding issues.